# How to create a UIPrintPaper to test UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate

Tags: swift, airprint, uiprintinteractioncntrler

Having written a `UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate`, I wish to unit test its paper selection functionality in `printInteractionController:choosePaper:`

Its declaration is:

```
optional func printInteractionController(_ printInteractionController: UIPrintInteractionController, choosePaper paperList: [UIPrintPaper]) -> UIPrintPaper
```

It is a simple matter of calling it with predefined UIPrintPaper values and checking the output. However I am unable to create UIPrintPaper instances. Here is how UIPrintPaper is declared:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_2)__TVOS_PROHIBITED @interface UIPrintPaper : NSObject 

+ (UIPrintPaper *)bestPaperForPageSize:(CGSize)contentSize withPapersFromArray:(NSArray<UIPrintPaper *> *)paperList; // for use by delegate. pass in list

@property(readonly) CGSize paperSize;
@property(readonly) CGRect printableRect;

@end
```

The paperSize and printableRect properties are readonly and there is no initializer to define them. How can I create UIPrintPaper to represent different paper sizes for my tests? (A4, US Letter, 4x6...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't control UIPrintPaper, but subclassing it to override its readonly properties is straighforward:

```
class FakePrintPaper: UIPrintPaper {

    private let size: CGSize
    override var paperSize: CGSize { return size }
    override var printableRect: CGRect  { return CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size) }

    init(size: CGSize) {
        self.size = size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIPrintPaper` class method `bestPaperForPageSize`:

```
let paper = UIPrintPaper.bestPaperForPageSize(CGSize(...), withPapersFromArray: [...])
```

I imagine you would want to use it like this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject { }

extension MyClass: UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate {
    func printInteractionController(printInteractionController: UIPrintInteractionController, choosePaper paperList: [UIPrintPaper]) -> UIPrintPaper {
        return UIPrintPaper.bestPaperForPageSize(CGSize(...), withPapersFromArray: paperList)
    }
}
```

Where CGSize is your paper size.

Comment: It's the same problem, how do I create UIPrintPaper in order to call this method? (its withPapersFromArray: is an array of UIPrintPaper)

Comment: @Clafou Edited my answer for the approach I think you want to take.

Comment: That's the implementation I had, but it turns out that bestPaperForPageSize doesn't always do what you need. Hence the need for me to write these unit tests (and also probably to implement my own logic instead – will see once I can write unit tests). My question is about creating UIPrintPaper so that I can unit test this.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.  I misunderstood the original question.  You may be able to use KVO to directly modify those properties.  Let me get back to you with an answer that allows you to modify those values directly.

Comment: @Clafou Ok, I think `UIPrintPaper` gets its `paperSize` and `printableRect` from its internal `PKPaper` object.  Header [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PKPaper.h).  Still digging...

Comment: Got it – thanks for your help. It's quite simple actually, Swift allows to subclass UIPrintPaper and override its readonly properties, replacing their values with the ones I wish.

Comment: Ah I didn't even consider subclassing.  Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to create UIPrintPaper. The Apple API calls:

```
- (UIPrintPaper*)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController choosePaper:(NSArray<UIPrintPaper *> *)paperList
```

... on your UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate with *an array of all UIPaper supported by your printer*. If you don't get the one you want, then the printer doesn't support it.

So instead of creating one, implement this delegate call, and return the correct UIPrintPaper from the params that the printer supports.

Comment: True, but as I explained in my question, I needed this for unit testing purposes. In this case I can't rely on a printer to provide the UIPaper instances required by the tests.

Comment: Why not? I use printer simulator for exactly this. You specify what paper it loads. Comes with xcode support pkg

Comment: Unit Tests are meant to be repeatable, fully automated, and self-contained.

Comment: Sure. Having your unit test spin up printer simulator as part of its setup() doesn't stop it from being that. It is silly not to use the tools given to you

Comment: Printer Simulator is for manual testing. I use it and I change printers and paper sizes for my manual tests, so if my unit tests rely on it they'll break all the time. Did you see the approved answer from 2 months ago? That solves the problem.

Comment: Yes i saw it. It is an anti-pattern (subclassing to overcome readonly), hence my comment -- the risk is that others see this and think the soln for regular printing is to subclass rather than use the method apple wants, which is my "answer". I appreciate that you find it easier to subclass than to automate printer simulator. That's a fair point.