# How can we set print size UIPrintInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to set A6 Page For Print. i'm using below code for print. but i can't find how i set pageSize and page formate that my print look better.

```
void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error) NSLog(@"Print error: %@", error);
};

UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;

NSData *pdfData = [self generatePDFDataForPrinting];
printController.printingItem = pdfData;


if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    [printController presentFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view
                            animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
} else {
    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [`UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate.printInteractionController:choosePaper:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintinteractioncontrollerdelegate/1618160-printinteractioncontroller?language=objc) to return [`UIPrintPaper.bestPaperForPageSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintpaper#bestPaperForPageSize) or some other desired size.

See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37551137/665456).

Comment: yes but not calling this method

- (UIPrintPaper *)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController choosePaper:(NSArray *)paperList
{
    CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(6 * 72, 4 * 72);
    return [UIPrintPaper bestPaperForPageSize:pageSize withPapersFromArray:paperList];
}